# Redirect to subdomain gives redirect loop error

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect, subdomain, geoip

This is my code, placed in my htaccess in the main directory of my domain. Trying to redirect country traffic (using mod_geoip) to my subdomain.

```
GeoIPEnable On

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

However, I'm getting a redirect loop error when I put it into practice. When I switch my Rewrite rule to go to domain.com and then put the file in sub.domain.com it seems to work. What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Anubhava for your help. I looked around a bit and found this modification that seemed to do the trick. The change was made to the `RewriteRule`.

```
GeoIPEnable On

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$ [NC]

RewriteRule !^(subdomain) http://www.subdomain.domain.com [L,R]
```

I put this in my .htaccess and it worked! I saw this use with redirecting with a subfolder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule with an additional condition to avoid redirect when host is already `sub.domain.com`:

```
GeoIPEnable On

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: That additional condition didn't seem to work. It actually seemed to overwrite the other condition and rule and just sent me to domain.com. Thanks for the suggestion though!